# Can't restore or backup Odoo Databases

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I am getting the following error. I can't backup and cant't restore any database. This will be a huge issue if the database crashes:

```
Database restore error: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_restore', u'--dbname=back', '--no-owner', '/tmp/tmpKY434e') error 1

Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmp40EUve/dump.sql', u'Live_GasandOil') error 1
```

Please help this is very critical

Comment: take a look at this link maybe it can help you https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/database-backup-error-postgres-subprocess-usr-bin-pg-dump-no-owner-file-tmp-tmpaa0o5q-dump-sql-u-ahlain-db01-error-1-118245

Comment: At first try to look into the Odoo log. There should be more information why the subprocess throw an error. If that's not helping try to call that process with command line. Use the the same user you're starting Odoo with.

Comment: You may find something here too:  https://github.com/odoo/docker/issues/234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was an extra table in the database which was not supposed to be there. on drooping that table i got that fixed.

Comment: how did you identif those extra table? is there any relations with others tables?